Advice on fine-tuning an email classifier for a Pharma company
I'm an intern working on implementing a binary email classifier for a client (Pharmaceutical company) and I need some advice on fine-tuning the model.
The model I'm using is Longformer (because it has a large context window suitable for my use case) and I've already trained it using 14 different combinations of hyperparameters. In the latest iteration, it seems my model not only overfits the training set but somehow the validation and test sets as well (I found this out when we tested the model on a separate dataset).
The target I'm hoping to achieve is to reduce the False Negative Rate (FNR) to less than 2%.
Regarding the dataset, I have around 8800 samples with roughly equal samples per class. This comes after extensive cleaning and data augmentation.
What I'm doing after training is using the validation set to find a reasonable threshold that I then use for predictions.
Here are some results from my recently trained model:
Validation set(Imbalanced, Negative(0) class in heavy majority):
Threshold: 0.9
Accuracy: 82.47%
FNR: 1.91%
False Positive Rate(FPR): 15.61%
F1 score: 0.64
Precision: 49%
Recall: 91%
ROC-AUC: 94%
Test Set(Imbalanced, Negative(0) class in heavy majority):
Accuracy: 84.79%
FNR: 1.51%
FPR: 13.69%
Given the threshold and the metrics from the validation data, you can see that the model is tending to predict models more often, hence the low FNR.
Here are the Hyperparameters I used for the recent training loop:
Learning rate: 1.5e-5
Learning rate scheduler: Cosine
Weight decay: 0.01
Epochs: 7
Dropout rate: 0.35
Class Weights: [0.9, 1.1]
Metric for best model: F1 score
Early stopping patience: 2
For the next iteration, I was thinking lowering the learning rate(to 1e-5) and increasing weight decay(0.03) and dropout rate(0.45) to address overfitting. But I'm not entirely confident. I'd ask my colleagues but they are from SWE backgrounds and don't have a good handle on this.
Some advice would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Cross Validated! The target I'm hoping to achieve is to reduce the False Negative Rate(FNR) to less than 2%. If this is the case, you can classify everything as positive and get 0%. If this is unacceptable (it probably is), why? Your particular reasons will matter and will inform next steps.

The actual purpose of this classifier is to detect "adverse effects" of medication on patients so it can be reported to appropriate authorities. So, right now the complete target is to keep FNR below 2% while keeping FPR below 10%.

If you look at the ROC curve, is there any point where you achieve those requirements?

Unfortunately, no. I just plotted the ROC curve and I need FPR(x-axis) <= 0.1 and TPR(y-axis) >= 0.98. If I draw straight lines through these points, they intersect above the ROC curve.

What if it did, though? How would you proceed to get that TPR-FPR pair?

I'll find the corresponding threshold that produced that TPR-FPR pair.
